# Can the word "proxy" be used as a preposition?

Tags: grammar, idioms, prepositions, word-usage

At the end of a sentence, I want to insert the following (parentheses included):

> (proxy my parents, of course).

E.g.,

> I sent my brother to his room (proxy my parents, of course).

But this doesn't sound right. I know that the preposition "via" is used this way quite frequently:

> I accessed the internet via my school laptop.

My gut tells me "(with my parents serving as proxy, of course)" is definitely idiomatically/grammatically correct, but it also gives me the feeling that that usage is tacky, and just doesn't sound like good writing.

So what can I do in this situation to both use "proxy" correctly and also form a well-written sentence that's nice on the ears? Can I use "proxy" as a preposition like I originally did?

Comment: Use of proxy that hasn't to do with tests, voting, or networks is quite strange except possibly when one is a go-between. Still, if I'm reading it, it's probably going to jar my reading flow. Certainly others will disagree, but I'll defer to them to do the voting.

Comment: You can certainly do it if (a) you want to, and (b) you think other people will understand your meaning. Given the entire context of your question I can understand your intent - but if all I had to go on was your example sentence, I probably wouldn't. You'd do better to express yourself in "normal" English, such as *I sent my brother to his room (**acting as a** proxy **for** my parents*, or *using my parents as proxy*). Or even more normally, *on behalf of my parents*, since "proxy" is a bit of an obscure word to many.

Comment: [This article](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/prepositions/p.htm) would suggest 'no' (quite strongly, in my opinion), but the OED might be a better place to check.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *on behalf of my parents* sounds much better. I'll use this.

Comment: @gragas: Or [*...on my parents' behalf*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+my+parents'+behalf%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: @Edwin: Looking at that page reminded me I've long been irritated by Orwell's [*Our civilization, **pace** Chesterton {blah blah}*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dHoUAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Our+civilization+pace+chesterton%22&dq=%22Our+civilization+pace+chesterton%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SZj-U5-VC4PY0QWQ-oHQBg&redir_esc=y). I don't recall *ever* hearing it used in conversation in almost 50 years since I first asked my English teacher what it meant. He told me ***pace*** there meant *after, since*, and it was years until I met it in print again, got confused by the semantics, and checked a dictionary.

Comment: ...anyway, my underlying point is if that page doesn't even list an *acknowledged* preposition, they're hardly likely to list OP's "creative" usage as one.

Comment: Do you mean (proxying for my parents of course?)  I'm not sure how to read *proxy my parents*  and things like *using my parents as proxy* means, to me, *I told my parents to tell my brother to go to his room*-  not the same thing at all.  All in all I'd probably say something like:  I had to send my brother to his room because my parents weren't here to do it.

Comment: @FF M-W give the prepositional usage of _pace_, but not for _proxy_. Though I'd probably read more into the omission of both in the above list.

Comment: @gragas Isn't _on behalf of my parents_ the exact opposite of what you intend? Your question says that the parents are acting as your proxy.

Comment: @Barmar’s comment is exactly why I wouldn’t use _proxy_ as a preposition: it's extremely vague and unclear. From your question, even with the context, I cannot figure out if you sent your brother to his room using your parents as the go-between, the ‘tool’ (i.e., they're the ones saying, “Go to your room!”, but you're the one who wanted him to go there really), or if you're acting as a proxy for your parents (who are perhaps away) by sending him to his room.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I  know what you mean, but you can't use 'proxy' that way.

I'd go with "on behalf of".

Or if you want to sound legalistic/pedantic then you could say "acting with authority delegated from".

Answer (score 0):

No.

*Proxy* is not a preposition - noun or verb only.

I would suggest using the term `indirectly through`:

> I sent my brother to his room (indirectly through my parents, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In my view "proxy" is a term used in legal matters.
A bank may write: You can vote either in person or by proxy (at a shareholder meeting). If you give a proxy it is a written statement saying that another person
will be acting on your behalf. "proxy" derives from procuracy, ultimately Latin pro for and cura care. It can't be used as a preposition.
And I think in normal everyday language there is no use for such a special bank term.